# How to submit by just selecting an option from a dropdown with jquery?

Tags: jquery, submit

http://fsc.no/timeplan_rommen_197.html

When you select a different week (uke) from a dropdown on the right or trainer from the left dropdown above the schedule, it submit automatically . You don't need to click Submit(Vis).

How do you submit when you just select an option from a dropdown list?

Can it be done with jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do by triggering the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event, like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Or, call the native event:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("form")[0].submit();
});
```

The above examples would make it happen with any `<select>` element, just give it a different selector like an ID, for example: `$("#mySelect")`, or a class if you have multiple, for example:

```
<select class="autoSubmit">
```

And bind it using:

```
$(".autoSubmit").change(function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
$("#myddl").change(function(){
$("#myform").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can submit a form using jquery code. in your case you need to submit the form when the user selects a new value in the drop down. this can be done as follows:

```
$('#dropdown-id').change(function() {
  $('#form-id').submit();
});
```